IBM MQ Remotely connect and query QueueStatistics like amqsmon
There is a sample tool named amqsmon that allows you to query Queue/Channel statistics on a QM, ie
mqm@server1 /opt/mqm/samp/bin $ ./amqsmon -m MYQM1 -t statistics -q MYLOCALQ1 -b

MonitoringType: QueueStatistics
QueueManager: 'MYQM1'
IntervalStartDate: '2024-08-13'
IntervalStartTime: '10.04.52'
IntervalEndDate: '2024-08-13'
IntervalEndTime: '10.09.52'
QueueStatistics: 0
  QueueName: 'MYLOCALQ1'
  CreateDate: '2024-07-22'
  CreateTime: '23.54.38'
  QueueType: Local
  ...

I need to be able to use this same tool or output but connecting remotely to a different queue manager on a different server, does anyone know how I can accomplish this?
i.e., be able to query this on 10.0.0.2 port 1548 queue manager named TEST2 over TCP/IP.
Can I use this sample included tool or should I need to script with external connector, i.e. python or similar? and if so, how do you query statistics like these?

That same sample can be used to connect as a client to remote qmgrs. You can either use amqsmonc to explicitly run as a client or set MQ_CONNECT_TYPE=CLIENT environment variable.
And then it's the standard MQ mechanisms for connections - MQSERVER or CCDT configurations.
Review the instructions here to prepare your queue manager for client connections.
Review the instructions here to set up the MQSERVER environment variable.

can you give me an example on where/how do I specify the IP/PORT of the listener running on QM1? , also, i believe i will need to allow or specify a channel or modify the existing SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN to allow it connections right?

I've added a link to Mark's answer to the page in IBM Docs that describes how to prepare your queue manager for client connections and set up the MQSERVER environment variable.

@MoragHughson thanks a lot for the links, now it makes more sense! :)
